# How to pass key as a value through a database model class in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

This is what my database looks like:

[Realtime Database Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5EVF.png)

And this is my model class:

```
class Registrations {
private var userEmail:String =""
private var verified:Boolean = false


constructor()
constructor(userEmail:String, verified:Boolean){
    this.userEmail = userEmail
    this.verified = verified

}


fun getUserEmail():String{
    return userEmail
}

fun setUserEmail(userEmail: String){
    this.userEmail = userEmail
}

fun getVerified():Boolean{
    return verified
}

fun setVerified(verified: Boolean){
    this.verified = verified
}
}
```

I am using a RecyclerAdapter to get the data and my code to do that is:

```
private fun getRegistrations() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Registrations").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                itemList!!.clear()
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    Log.d("ITEM", snapshot.toString())

                    val item = snapshot.getValue(Registrations::class.java)

                    itemList!!.add(item!!)
                }
                registrationsAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
}

}
```

Now as you can see in the database image how do I pass the key value(email of the user) as a value to the model class?

I have tried creating an object but I am doing something wrong/don't know how to, any help is appreciated.

Also, this app is in production so I can't change the data to have email as a value in firebase now.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always recommended that the fields in the class must match the ones in the database. So if a node in the database contains two fields, `verified` and `activationCode`, then the class should contain the same.

> this app is in production so I can't change the data to have email as a value in fFirebase now.

So if you cannot add the email as a value, which I doubt as it's a really simple update operation, then you can only read the key and use the setter to add in your object like this:

```
val item = snapshot.getValue(Registrations::class.java)
val userEmail = snapshot.getKey()
item.setUserEmail(userEmail)
itemList!!.add(item!!)
```